# Mismatch on trying to update chart series formula

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I can't figure out why I am getting a Mismatch when I am trying to update the Pie chart. Below is a test snippet. Particularly the issue is with the last statment, trying to update the series formula for the chart. I've tried a few methods but every instance where I use a range to update the chart it throws me a mismatch.

```
Private Sub UpdateAnalytics()

Dim CategoryPreview As Range
Dim ChartValues As Variant
Dim ChartXValues As Variant

    With Sheets("Analytics")
    Set CategoryPreview = Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Find("Page 4", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If 1 <> 1 Then
        CategoryPreview.Resize(1, 3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        CategoryPreview.Resize(1, 3).Copy Destination:=CategoryPreview.Offset(-1, 0)
        CategoryPreview.Offset(-1, 0) = 1
        CategoryPreview.Offset(-1, 1) = 1
    ElseIf 1 = 1 Then
        CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        CategoryPreview.Resize(1, 3).Copy Destination:=CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 0)
        CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 0) = 2
        CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 1) = 2
    End If

    .Range("AnnualSpent") = "=SUM(" & Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Address & ")"

    'Add new tab to the pie chart
    ChartXValues = Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    ChartValues = Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B1").End(xlDown))

    .ChartObjects("AnalyticsChart").Activate


       ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
       Selection.Formula = "=SERIES(,Analytics!" & ChartXValues & ",Analytics!" & ChartValues & ",1)"    <<<<< Mismatch happens here
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Range(.Range("A1")  ~~>  .Range(.Range("A1")   Put a period before every range.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it with this

```
Private Sub UpdateAnalytics()
    Dim CategoryPreview As Range
    Dim ChartValues As String 'Stored as String instead of variant
    Dim ChartXValues As String 'Stored as String instead of variant
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim Srs As Series
        With Sheets("Analytics")
            Set CategoryPreview = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Find("Page 4", LookIn:=xlValues) '<~~ add period .Range(. range("a1'
            If 1 <> 1 Then
                CategoryPreview.Resize(1, 3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                CategoryPreview.Resize(1, 3).Copy Destination:=CategoryPreview.Offset(-1, 0)
                CategoryPreview.Offset(-1, 0) = 1
                CategoryPreview.Offset(-1, 1) = 1
            ElseIf 1 = 1 Then
                CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                CategoryPreview.Resize(1, 3).Copy Destination:=CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 0)
                CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 0) = 2
                CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 1) = 2
            End If

            .Range("AnnualSpent") = "=SUM(" & Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Address & ")"

            'Add new tab to the pie chart
            ChartXValues = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Address 'add period, captured address for a dynamic chart
            ChartValues = .Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Address 'add period, captured address for a dynamic chart

            Set Cht = .ChartObjects("AnalyticsChart").Chart
            Set Srs = Cht.SeriesCollection(1)
            Srs.Formula = "=SERIES(,Analytics!" & ChartXValues & ",Analytics!" & ChartValues & ",1)" 'Updated chart via the formula
        End With
End Sub
```

Though, what I don't quite understand is that I had to keep the Cht and Srs variables or it wouldn't work. Why would storing the chart and series be any different from using the following?

```
.ChartObjects("AnalyticsChart").SeriesCollection(1).Formula = "=SERIES(,Analytics!" & ChartXValues & ",Analytics!" & ChartValues & ",1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Private Sub UpdateAnalytics()

    Dim CategoryPreview As Range
    Dim ChartValues As Variant
    Dim ChartXValues As Variant
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim Srs As Series
        With Sheets("Analytics")
            Set CategoryPreview = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Find("Page 4", LookIn:=xlValues) '<~~ add period .Range(. range("a1'
            If 1 <> 1 Then
                CategoryPreview.Resize(1, 3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                CategoryPreview.Resize(1, 3).Copy Destination:=CategoryPreview.Offset(-1, 0)
                CategoryPreview.Offset(-1, 0) = 1
                CategoryPreview.Offset(-1, 1) = 1
            ElseIf 1 = 1 Then
                CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                CategoryPreview.Resize(1, 3).Copy Destination:=CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 0)
                CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 0) = 2
                CategoryPreview.Offset(1, 1) = 2
            End If

            .Range("AnnualSpent") = "=SUM(" & Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Address & ")"

            'Add new tab to the pie chart
            ChartXValues = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)) ' add period
            ChartValues = .Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B1").End(xlDown)) 'add period

            '.ChartObjects("AnalyticsChart").Activate

            Set Cht = .ChartObjects("AnalyticsChart").Chart
            Set Srs = Cht.SeriesCollection(1)
            With Srs
                .XValues = ChartXValues
                .Values = ChartValues
            End With
           'Selection.Formula = "=SERIES(,Analytics!" & ChartXValues & ",Analytics!" & ChartValues & ",1)"    <<<<< Mismatch happens here
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried a form of this before as well. I end up with a chart that does show the category names but no pie chart. I did try your code, though, to be sure. I got the same result that I had previously.

Comment: Your idea did help me find the solution, though.